# Apple's Round Checkmarks - Where and When are they used?

Tags: ios, checkbox, user-experience

We are building a cross platform app, and a decision maker on my team (who is an Apple user) wants all of our "Select to delete" checkboxes to be round, "Like Apple's Mail and Messages apps".

[image]
[image]

I personally find this confusing, I think they look like radio buttons. He disgarees that anyone would confuse round circles for radio buttons.

Apple's HIG about checkboxes doesn't specifically state that checkboxes should be a specific shape [Apple's HIG on Checkboxes](https://developer.apple.com/macos/human-interface-guidelines/buttons/checkboxes/)

Apple's Sample Code shows square checkboxes, but that's not selecting to DELETE an item [Apple's TableViewCell Sample Code](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Accessory/Introduction/Intro.html)

**Have all iOS devices always used round checkmarks to delete items, or is this a new change?**

Where and when does iOS use round checkmarks?

Comment: The HIG section you linked to is for macOS. The iOS HIG says nothing about checkboxes. As an iOS user I don't find the round checkboxes confusing, particularly in the context shown. Why would a list of items to be selected use a radio button? People use more than the shape of a control to indicate what is happening. This context is clearly about selecting more than one thing. I also have to say that radio buttons are not a very common UI element in iOS. iOS doesn't support them natively. A more common UI for the "select one from many" is a picker since it is more economical use of screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Round buttons are the default and standard in multiple selection of iOS table views, and always have been, as far as I know. You can see this in the second screenshot of the ["Buttons" page in Apple's iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/controls/buttons/). Try this Swift sample code that invokes `UITableView`'s default multiple selection mode:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
        tableView.setEditing(true, animated: false)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")
        cell?.textLabel?.text = String(indexPath.row)
        return cell!
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 15
    }
}
```

The above code produces this interface (taken on the iPhone X iOS 11.3 Simulator):

[image: UITableView with default round selection checkmark circles]

Answer (score 0):

A common case for IOS to use round check marks in their design is when they are designing for color impaired users. Since these users can't rely on the colors green and red to provide them information, these check marks are used instead. Instead of green a check mark is used, instead of red use an X is used.

If you are just selecting items to delete I would consider using numerical values in the round icon to identify how many messages the user is selecting.